# Kafka / Logstash output to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

I have a Logstash 6.2x setup where I read Kafka input and write the output to an Elasticsearch instance and am running into issues when using if/else

Logstash config looks like

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => '192.168.2.66:9092,192.168.2.67:9092,192.168.2.68:9092'
    topics => ["linum", "newdata"]
    codec => "json"
    type => "kafka"
    tags => ["linumsrvr1"]
    decorate_events => true
    }
}
output {
    if [topic] == "linum" {
        elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["192.168.2.32:9200"]
        action => "index"
        index => "linum-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
          }
   stdout {codec => rubydebug}
     } else {
     [kafka][topic_id] == "newdata" {
        elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["192.168.2.32:9200"]
        index => "newdata-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
          }
   stdout {codec => rubydebug}
     }
   }
}
```

I am able to get data into Elasticsearch when output contains the 4 lines starting/ending with "elasticsearch { ..... / dd}"

For some reason I dont seem to get any data being sent to Elasticsearch when I use "IF" or  "IF" + "ELSE" statements.

I would like to create two separate indexes for the two topics.

I will appreciate some guidance around what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You could do this with Kafka Connect and Single Message Transforms. If that is an option you would consider I can post details in an answer.